# In JMeter, how do I assign the response time from a HTTP Sampler into a variable?

Tags: jmeter

I'm probably missing something basic, but I can figure out how to get the response time from a HTTP Sampler, preferably without using bean-shell or any scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that it is not possible to do this without scripting.

With [Beanshell Post Processor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) it'll be as simple as follows:

```
long duration = prev.getTime();
```

You can store it to JMeter Variable to re-use anywhere you'll need it.

```
vars.put("duration", String.valueOf(duration));
```